# Official documentations about Rest API "Sharelink" paramters

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api

From where i can get the official documentation from Microsoft regarding the "Sharelink" REST API endpoint specification, mainly the values and purpose of the parameters passed inside the body. as I can not find any official documentations. any advice please?

1- Method:- `POST`

2- URL:- _`api/web/Lists('ListGUID')/GetItemByID('1')?['ID']}')/Sharelink`

3- Body:-

```
{

    "request":{
        "createLink":true,
        "settings":{
            "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
            "linkKind":6,
            "role":1,
            "restrictShareMembership":false,
            "updatePassword":true,
            "password":"***",
            "scope":0
        }
    }
}
```

now the above link will create an anonymous link with Read-only permission, but not sure how

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the documentation for the endpoint directly. But since PNPjs is library that is mounted on top of the REST API, maybe you can find your answer by analyzing how the library calls at this endpoint:

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/sharing/

Also, this is the most documentation I found about this endpoint on a Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1282962/what-is-the-rest-api-endpoint-that-i-can-use-share

Comment: thanks a lot for the great links and help, will check them all.

Comment: But for example I used the browser developer tool to inspect the parameters that will be sent from the SharePoint UI when we share files using Anyone link or using "People you choose".. then i added those parameters to the custom REST API and it worked.. but can we guarantee that those parameters will not get changed in the future since there is not any official documentation about those parameters and the option we have.. did you get my point?

Comment: You cannot guarantee it won't change, because it's an endpoint on testing / beta phase. As Microsoft is telling in the documentation.

Comment: so how i can implement this requirement then inside my custom rest api?

Comment: also where did you find that it is on testing / beta phase?

Comment: I cannot find it anymore, I though this was somewhere in a Microsoft post about this endpoint. If the endpoint is on beta, you cannot safely assume that it won't change, you will have to have it in mind when telling it to your client. But since this is coming from Microsoft and not from you, it shouldn't be a problem to justify.

Comment: Found it, it's on the PNPjs link that I posted here.

Comment: where exactly you found it inside the link ?